# timepicker Working on local but not in production

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, timepicker

i am using laravel 5.5 with

> jquery.timepicker.js

trying to set time selector output is fine on local here is screenshot
[image: working screenshot]

but after upload on server its not working output is like
[image: shit image]

whats the problem help me thanks

Comment: its look like your CSS file of timepicker is not found on production

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: There is no error on consol please check http://rahuldev.ga and try to book a car

Comment: @ShreeKhanal can u check this please

Answer (score 0):

Its not working and no one answering my question so i use alternate html select & option attribute for make time select drop down
and its working fine